# Bootstrap horizontal form element has -15px margin

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a site with bootstrap. If you see my [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6xrwvnch/1/) example, you will see that the red bordered div has a `-15px` margin at left and right. This is because if the `form-group` and `row` I think. But all the other elements is in their place. Why is it?

**CSS**

```
.tokenizer {
  border: 1px solid #f00;
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
  min-height: 100px;
  color: #555
}
```

If I remove my `.tokenizer` the result will be the same, because `col-xs-12` also have this `width: 100%`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the `form-group` class and it'll be ok. You don't need it around a text-area like this without a label.

Answer (score 0):

Well it is not about the width its about the visibility you are giving a border to a div whose visibility is hidden. Oppose to that if your div's visibility is set to "none". Then it won't be the issue.

i.e.

```
display:none;
```

but the bootstrap class "hidden" is giving it to

```
display:hidden;
```

As the hidden elements are there , they are occupying the space they are just not showing it you whereas the visibility none option completely removes the element from the page.
https://jsfiddle.net/6xrwvnch/1/

Comment: And yeah the -15px margin is due to .form-group class which is setting this margin. I don't why but its there